# appropriate way to change the data type of a date column from character to date-time in R

Tags: r, date

I am new into the R world. So, I have a data frame that have two date columns that comprises of *date and time*, but stored as a **character**, so I want to use the difftime() function to make a column that could store in seconds the time between the two date columns. I tried changing the data type of the date column(start_time) from **character** to a **date-time** format severally, using different date-time functions,, just so I could be able use the difftime() function on it, but to no avail . Please, help.

Below I uploaded an image of the table and pasted the codes I used  together with the errors they've returned. where start_*time and end*_time are the date columns.

[image]

1

```
all_trips3 <- as.POSIXlt(all_trips3$start_time)
```

got this error after I ran it "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(all_trips3$start_time) :    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

2

```
all_trips3$start_time <- (strptime(all_trips3$start_time, "%m/%d/%y")
```

It ran but made date column(start_time) into NA values

3

```
 all_trips3$start_time <- as.POSIXct(all_trips3$start_time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", tz = Sys.timezone())
```

ran too, but it made the date(start_time) column into NA values

4. saw this here on stackflow while looking for solutions

```
all_trips3 <- all_trips3 %>%
  mutate(across(c(start_time, end_time), as.POSIXct,
                format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

ran too, but had my date columns filled with NA values

Comment: Please provide data without using images next time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: okay, thank you. I am new on here too, so I hardly know my way around.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with `strptime`!

Consider this small example data frame.

```
df
#   X1 X2 X3     start_time        stop_time X5
# 1  0  0  0 2/19/2022 5:36 11/19/2022 15:36  0
# 2  0  0  0 2/19/2022 5:36 11/19/2022 15:36  0
# 3  0  0  0 2/19/2022 5:36 11/19/2022 15:36  0
```

Then identify your time columns,

```
tc <- grep('start_time|stop_time', names(df))
```

and

```
df[tc] <- lapply(df[tc], strptime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

df
#   X1 X2 X3          start_time           stop_time X5
# 1  0  0  0 2022-02-19 05:36:00 2022-11-19 15:36:00  0
# 2  0  0  0 2022-02-19 05:36:00 2022-11-19 15:36:00  0
# 3  0  0  0 2022-02-19 05:36:00 2022-11-19 15:36:00  0
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0, 0, 0), X2 = c(0, 0, 0), X3 = c(0, 0, 
0), start_time = c("2/19/2022 5:36", "2/19/2022 5:36", "2/19/2022 5:36"
), stop_time = c("11/19/2022 15:36", "11/19/2022 15:36", "11/19/2022 15:36"
), X5 = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: It ran without any error, but the columns are filled with the NA values, same with other functions I have tried.

Comment: @ZainabZanna Then make it reproducible, good luck!

Comment: I tried again by dropping the data frame I was using, I usually save tables in a new data frame whenever I make significant changes to it, so I could easily go back to it when necessary. So, I ran the two codes of line you provided, and it worked!! Thank you much. @jay.sf

Comment: I would really appreciate if you will help explain to me  how the codes exactly work, and what each line or function does. Thank you.

Comment: @ZainabZanna Glad it worked for you. `grep` is actually just another way to find the time columns you could also do `tc <- c("start_time", "stop_time")`. You can easily look up the documentation how a function works by typing `?lapply` or `?strptime`. I even recommend you to do that with every new function you are using, if you want to learn R thoroughly. Also to play through and try to understand the examples given there, and you'll quickly become a great R programmer. :)